# How to trigger consistent events in single browser console in one time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, console

For example I would like to control multiple”online”webpages ,such as google.com ,with only a sequence of consistent codes on browser console(ctrl+shift+j in windows system)for consistent action "such as clicking button A in A web and jumping to web B automatically , then clicking button B in B web."

(as usual,I must type other codes in refreshed console once I jump to anther webpage to change html)

For example:

//on the console1

```
`document.getElementbyid(“id1”).click()
```

`

//id1 is inside the web1

```
`window.open(“link_of_new_webpage”,”_self”)`
```

//I understand that it will be just a new page with new console.
//but I mean I was looking forward to some kind of these things.

//and below is id2 inside web2 in console2

```
`document.getElementbyid(“id2”).click()`
```

in conclusion i want a console likely showed below

```
document.getElementbyid(“id1”).click()
window.open(“link_of_new_webpage”,”_self”)`
document.getElementbyid(“id2”).click()
```

//the code above is actually consistent!

//not like code below

```
document.getElementbyid(“id1”).click()//in console 1 in web1
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
document.getElementbyid(“id2”).click()//in console 2 in web2
```

Plz someone helps me or tell me that it cannot be fulfilled
(in fact ,I was freshman in JavaScript and Html)
I promise I will use these tools in correct way.thx beyond description !!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this on a client facing site I'm afraid what I believe you're asking to do is impossible for a myriad of security reasons. If you're just looking to run these executions locally though you're in luck. Headless browsers are commonly used in testing as well as web scraping and allow you to program commands as if a user was interacting directly with the browser. If you're looking to stay within the confines of JS a popular option is [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

Best of luck

Comment: Thx a lot , I will try it from scratch .Absolutely appreciate it!